# Plotting multiple dataframes using pairplot seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I was wondering if it were possible to input multiple dataframes into pairplot seaborn. The dataframes have the same column headers, but they each contain different data values (i.e. df1 --> # of schools in county, df2 --> unemployment rate in county). I want to compare the values contained in each dataframe in a single visual like pairplot.

I looked at the pairplot docs and the examples only use 1 dataframe. I'm going to assume that pairplot is designed to only handle 1 dataframe, so do I have to merge the dataframes before using pairplot? Is there something like pairplot that handles multiple dataframes?

Column Headers: CountyName,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016

*Have 8 different dataframes

Comment: Merge them to a single DataFrame, and plot it?

Comment: No, pairplot or any other function I know of uses a single dataset. This makes sense from a design perspective, otherwise it would not be clear how more then one dataset relate to each other. There are examples in [the seaborn docs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html) using several categories (seaborn calls them `hue`s) in a single pairgrid.